# How can I create control that depends on another control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [Leva js](https://github.com/pmndrs/leva) to create a simple panel that includes a button that creates an array of random numbers. The length of that array should depends on the property `datasetLength` of Leva panel but it seems not to work because of:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'levaConfig' before initialization

Here my code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useControls, button } from "leva";

function App() {
  const [dataset, setDataset] = useState<Datum[]>(computeRandomDataset);

  const levaConfig = useControls({
    "update dataset": button(() => setDataset(computeRandomDataset)),
    datasetLength: {
      value: 300,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 1,
    },
  });

  function computeRandomDataset() {
    const datasetLength = levaConfig.datasetLength; // <-- ERROR
    return createDataset(datasetLength);
  }

  return <h1>Vite + React</h1>;
}

export default App;

function createDataset(datasetLength: number) {
  const dataset = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < datasetLength; i++) {
    dataset.push(Math.random());
  }
  return dataset;
}
```

The result should be this:
[image]

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed why this should dolce my problem?

Comment: Actually you were calling the function in useState that function extracting the data from useControl, So the Point browser still reading useState line and useControl is initialize after useState, So In the useState line it doesn't exist yet

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed thank you for the explanation. the error disappears but the dataset length doesn't change. it's like it doen't listen the levaConfig updates

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed, answers go down there. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access `levaConfig.datasetLength` before it has been initialized. The `levaConfig` object is being created asynchronously, and trying to use its properties directly during the initialization of your component can lead to reference errors.

To solve this problem, you can use the `useEffect` hook to update the dataset when the `datasetLength` property changes. You can do it like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useControls, button } from "leva";

function App() {
  const [dataset, setDataset] = useState<Datum[]>(computeRandomDataset);

  const levaConfig = useControls({
    "update dataset": button(() => setDataset(computeRandomDataset)),
    datasetLength: {
      value: 300,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 1,
      onChange: (value) => setDatasetLength(value),
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setDataset(computeRandomDataset(levaConfig.datasetLength));
  }, [levaConfig.datasetLength]);

  function computeRandomDataset(length: number) {
    return createDataset(length);
  }

  return <h1>Vite + React</h1>;
}

export default App;

function createDataset(datasetLength: number) {
  const dataset = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < datasetLength; i++) {
    dataset.push(Math.random());
  }
  return dataset;
}
```

This should resolve the reference error you were encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You should try initialising the `levaConfig` const before your `useState` statement. Because your `useState` prop is trying to access the `levaConfig`.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useControls, button } from "leva";

function App() {
  const levaConfig = useControls({
    "update dataset": button(() => setDataset(computeRandomDataset)),
    datasetLength: {
      value: 300,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 1,
    },
  });

  const [dataset, setDataset] = useState<Datum[]>(computeRandomDataset);

  function computeRandomDataset() {
    const datasetLength = levaConfig.datasetLength; // <-- ERROR
    return createDataset(datasetLength);
  }

  return <h1>Vite + React</h1>;
}

export default App;

function createDataset(datasetLength: number) {
  const dataset = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < datasetLength; i++) {
    dataset.push(Math.random());
  }
  return dataset;
}
```